# Urn has 100 balls, 60 black. Take 10 and put them back. $X_{n} = $ black balls in the previous extraction.

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation

I have an Urn with 100 balls, 60 of them black. I start by taking 10 balls at random, taking note of how many black balls are in those 10 (let's call that $X_1$) and putting them back in the urn. Now I repeat the process taking out $X_1$ balls, noting the amount of black balls in those (call that $X_2$) and putting them back.

Now I consider the random variables $X_{n}$ defined as $X_{1} = 10 $ and for $n \geq 2$ $X_n =$ the amount black balls in the $(n-1)$th extraction.

Find $E(X_n)$ and $X_n \rightarrow _{a.s.} 0$

I was having some trouble with the first part, specifically if conditioning only to the last step is right.

My attempted solution

$$ E (X_n) = E( E(X_n | X_{n-1})) $$

Since $ X_{n} | X_{n-1} = k \sim H(100, 60, k) $ we have that $E(X_n | X_{n-1} = k ) = \frac{3}{5} k \{ X_{n-1} = k \} $. Then,

$$ E( E(X_n | X_{n-1})) = E(\frac{3}{5} X_{n-1}) = \frac{3}{5} E(X_{n-1}) $$

We know that $ E(X_{1}) = 6$, so we can compute $E(X_2) = 2 \frac{ 3^2}{5} $ and by induction we prove that for $ n \geq 2$, $E(X_n) = 2 \frac{3^n}{5^{n-1}} = 10(\frac{3}{5})^n$.

We want to prove that $P (Lim X_{n} = 0) = 1 $ then since $X_{n} \geq 0$ we need $Lim P ( X_{n} \geq \frac{1}{n} ) = 0 $. Using Markov's inequality we have that

$$ P( X_{n} \geq \frac{1}{n} ) \leq n E(X_{n}) = 10n (\frac{3}{5})^n \rightarrow 0 $$

So $P (Lim X_n = 0 ) = 1$.

Any comments would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "put them back"? It sounds like reinsertion, but that would mean $E(X_n)=6, \forall n$...

Comment: Sorry, without noticing I deleted the explanation of the problem before submitting. It's there now. You do reinsert the balls you take out, but the number of balls you take out each time is dependent on how many black balls you found in the previous extraction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your arguments are sound to me.

Another way to show that $X_n\to 0$ almost surely is the following. Let $Y_n$ be the number of blacks you get drawing always 10 balls, that is, after drawing $X_{n-1}$ balls, you draw another $10-X_{n-1}$. Clearly the event $\{X_n\geq k\}$ is included in the event $\{Y_n\geq k\}$, so $P(X_n\geq 1)\leq P(Y_n\geq 1)$, and if you intersect these events you maintain the inequality, that is

$$
P(X_1\geq 1\cap X_2\geq 1\cap\cdots \cap X_n\geq 1)\leq P(Y_1\geq 1\cap Y_2\geq 1\cap\cdots \cap Y_n\geq 1)
$$
But the $Y_n$ are independent, so

$$
P(X_1\geq 1\cap X_2\geq 1\cap\cdots \cap X_n\geq 1)\leq P(Y_1\geq 1)^n=(1-P(Y_1=0)^n=(1-0.4^{10})^n
$$
and clearly the last term approaches 0 as $n\to \infty$. Since $X_n$ is discrete and non increasing, $P(X_n\to 0)=P(\exists N: X_N=0)=1-P(X_n\geq 1,\forall n)$. Now, $\{X_n\geq 1, \forall n\}=\cap \{X_i\geq 1,i=1,\ldots,n\}$, which are nested events, so $P(X_n\geq 1, \forall n)=\lim_{n\to \infty} P(X_i\geq 1,i=1,\ldots,n)$, which we showed to be 0.